# sudo apt update: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, postgresql

I have been trying to install pgadmin4 for a while, (but no success) so I can have a GUI to navigate postgresql server. Don't why but simple update command is also failing now. What did I do? where is wrong?

```
kia@fficeUbuntu:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
[sudo] password for kia: 
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Present contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/
jammy-pgdg main
```

[image]

how to rectify this problem?

update: as per accepted answer, this fixed it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's split across two lines, and shouldn't be. The `jammy-pgdg main` should be immediately after the `apt/` then a space. So:

`deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jammy pgdg-main`

All on one line.

Comment: Wow that was an easy fix but hard to find. My only question is: how, why and when it went to the next line? I am sure I have not opened this file before? was it due to some bad installation?

Comment: Likely a simple copy and paste error. It's easily done, we've all been there. Glad it's fixed.